# 2 out of 4 Font Awesome icons not showing

Tags: font-awesome

i added the Font Awesome link tag in my index file, and added some Font Awesome icons.
However, 2 are showing, but the other 2 are not showing.

Did anybody else experience this problem and knows how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
<section id="timeline" class="icons bg-light">
<h1>Timeline</h1>
<div class="flex-items">
  <div>
    <i class="fas fa-rings-wedding fa-2x"></i>
  <div>
    <h3>Gemeentehuis</h3>
    <p>11:00 AM</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <i class="fas fa-utensils fa-2x"></i>
    <div>
      <h3>Diner</h3>
      <p>17:00 PM</p>
    </div>
  <div>
    <i class="fas fa-hands-heart fa-2x"></i>
  <div>
    <h3>Ceremonie</h3>
    <p>20:30 PM </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  <div>
  <i class="fas fa-glass-cheers fa-2x"></i>
  <div>
    <h3>Avondfeest</h3>
    <p>22:00PM</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Link tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Comment: Could you please show some code how you included font awesome and how you are using the icons for both, the ones which are working and the ones which are not ...

Comment: If two icons are working and two are not, it's quite probable you are using a wrong classname (for instance a typo ...)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer,  I added my code above, its the wedding rings and the hands holding hearts that are not showing.

Comment: I guess some icons are available only with PRO.

Comment: Ok thanks, then i'll have to find some other icons to add.

Comment: Yes, @ksa is right. If you look at https://fontawesome.com/icons/rings-wedding and https://fontawesome.com/icons/hands-heart there is a clear indication, that they require a PRO license.